# Engagement Studio - Create an action based off a page view

Tags: pardot

I have a very specific use case for you and I would be very thankful if anyone has ideas for us, thank you!

We are in Engagement Studio and have reached a point where we want to tell Engagement Studio whether or not someone has viewed a page on our site that we are hosting. If they have viewed the page, we want to send them down path A, if they haven't viewed the page, we want to send them down path B. We want to do this exact process for 600 different websites. Here are our requirements:

We have over 600 different domains that we own, so we do not have one domain that is specifically tied to Pardot.

We cannot use a Pardot hosted page because that can only be used on one domain, we have 600 different domains

We are going to take the Java script tracking code and insert it in our own landing pages

Those landing pages are NOT hosted in Pardot because again we have 600 unique domains not one single domain

Please let us know if it is possible to do this in Pardot within Engagement Studio or not, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with out the box functionality.

**Assumption:**

- That there is 1 engagement programme covering all the 600 different domains.
- A prospect is required to enter the engagement programme once, even though they may have visited multiple domains.

**Answer:**

1. Ensure the Pardot Tracking JS is on every page covering the 600 domains.
2. Setup a [Page Action](http://help.pardot.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2128468-using-page-actions?b_id=11139)
   Include wildcard URL with an * (asterisk) which will ensure all sub pages are also covered by the Page Action. Then set the Completion Action to 'add a tag' and name a [tag](http://help.pardot.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2127247-tags-overview?b_id=11139).
3. Create an engagement programme to include a 'Rule' that assess the prospect tag created above. This will enable you send them down Path A or B